# I want an AlertDialog that open itself after closing

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I have an AlertDialog that I close by pressing a button but I want to open it again or open on top of itself

**what I want is a way to open it again without closing or after closing without clicking on any button**
here is the code

```
FutureBuilder<DropDown>(
                future: getDropData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    DropDown dropdown = snapshot.data;
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
                      child: Container(
                        //   width: wide / 12,
                        height: high / 15,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          color: maincolor,
                          splashColor: accentcolor,
                          onPressed: () {
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              child: AlertDialog(
                                title: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0),
                                      child: Center(child: Text("احتر القسم")),
                                    ),
                                    Divider(
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      thickness: 2,
                                      height: 1,
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                elevation: 8,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                                scrollable: false,
                                content: Container(
                                  height: 1000,
                                  width: 400,
                                  child: ListView.builder(
                                    itemCount: dropdown.categories.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      return Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            top: 8.0, right: 8, left: 8),
                                        child: Container(
                                          //  width: wide / 4,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                255, 255, 255, .64),
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                Radius.circular(12)),
                                          ),
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              FlatButton(
                                                  //color: maincolor,
                                                  onPressed: () {
                                                    setState(() {
                                                      categoryID = dropdown
                                                          .categories[index]
                                                          .categoryId;
                                                    });
                                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                  },
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    dropdown
                                                        .categories[index].name,
                                                    style: GoogleFonts.cairo(
                                                        color: maincolor,
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.w600,
                                                        fontSize: 15),
                                                  )),
                                              Divider(
                                                color: Colors.grey,
                                                height: 1,
                                                thickness: 1,
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            "اختر",
                            style: GoogleFonts.cairo(
                                color: accentcolor,
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        strokeWidth: 12,
                        backgroundColor: maincolor,
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }),
```

When I click any of the buttons on the alert dialog it closes
[image: AlertDialog Preview]

**what I want is a way to open it again without closing or after closing without clicking on any button**

**ANY HELP WILL BE APPRECIATED**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

for closing dialog

Answer (score 1):

The `showDialog` ia a Future, so you can use then, catchError, onComplete.
Use then or onComplete to run anything you want after the first dialog is closed.

```
showDialog(
    child: AlertDialog(...)
).then((){
   // Your code goes here
   // It will run after the dialog is closed
});
```

An easy way to run the same dialog is to make a function to open it:

```
Future _showDialog(BuildContext buildContext){
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    child: AlertDialog(...)
  )
}
```

and than you would do something like this:

```
_showDialog(
    buildContext: context
).onComplete((){
   // Your code goes here
   // It will run after the dialog is closed
   _showDialog() //to Show again
});
```

If you have any troubles because of the context, use a scaffoldKey and change the context of the dialog:

```
// Set it just at the top of your main widget
final _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

showDialog(
      context: _scaffoldKey.currentContext,
      ...)

// Set this parm on your scaffold
key: _scaffoldKey,
```

Comment: I really want to thank you for the effort but it doesn't work it opens the same dialog twice and the data doesn't change, did I miss understand something

Comment: The data inside the dialog must be coming from some state manager like Provider. You need to use variables and change their values with the interactions made by the user. Or you may pass them as parameter.

Comment: this what I do I think?

Comment: You may use setState too, but there are better state management solutions out there. Take a look: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple